# Xamarin.Forms ListView with ReactiveUI does not update new items

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm, reactiveui

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app. It have `SearchBar` in the NavigationBar, `ListView` in the ContentPage and a Entry with AddButton in the bottom. When user click on the `AddButton` the text in the Entry adds to the realm mobile database. Which autorefresh the `IEnumerable`. The ListView that is `bind` to IEnumerable `auto updates`.

```
 public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{

    public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public string Query { get; set; }

    public string NewCompany { get; set; }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddCompanyCommand { get; set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, IEnumerable<Company>> SearchCommand { get; set; }

    Realm _realm;

    public MainViewModel()
    {

        _realm = Realm.GetInstance();

        Companies = _realm.All<Company>();

        AddCompanyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await AddButtonClicked());
        SearchCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<Unit, IEnumerable<Company>>(
            _ =>

            SortCollection()
            );


        SearchCommand.ToProperty(this, nameof(Companies));

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Query).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(this, x => x.SearchCommand);


    }

    async Task AddButtonClicked()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NewCompany))
        {
            _realm.Write(() =>
            {
                _realm.Add(new Company { Name = NewCompany });
            });
            NewCompany = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<Company> SortCollection()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Query))
        {
            Companies = Companies.Where(x => x.Name != string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            Companies = Companies.Where(x => x.Name.IndexOf(Query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }

        return Companies;


    }

}
```

Recently when I added Search Logic to the ViewModel the ListView is not Auto Updating. I either have to `search` or restart the app to display the `new item` in the ListView. When I comment out the following line the ListView starts auto updating.

```
 SearchCommand.ToProperty(this, nameof(Companies));
```

But then it stops displaying Search Results. I want both Auto updating with new item and displaying search result  functionalities in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your `public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }` isn't notifying property change events.

Comment: But it start notifying if I comment out: " SearchCommand.ToProperty(this, nameof(Companies));".

Comment: This same line which  is interfering with updating ListView with new Items, is correctly updating the ListView with SearchResults.

Comment: Your not doing anything with your ToProperty.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need to tell the runtime that the property has changed so you need to implement notify property changed interface 
Look at this another stackoverflow thread.

[Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist/10595688#10595688)

Also there is is a plugin named fody which automatically injects propertychanged code into every setter of the properties in the project. Without needing you to do anything.

Install both of them in the project where you are writing your properties, it will automatically inject property changed code while compiling. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/

Comment: I am using realm and it updates the collection and notifies the view automatically. I am already using ReactiveUI.Fody. But I don't need that on my Companies collection.

Comment: ObserableAsPropertyHelper does inotifyprooertychanged notifications.